# powershell - looping through XML created correct number of nodes but the attribute values are are bundled up

Tags: xml, powershell, loops, foreach-object

I have this Powershell function:

```
function reportxml {

$logdir = "C:\\Documents\scriptOutput"
$XML_Path = $logdir + '\TR.xml'
$XML_NEW_PATH = $logdir + '\TestResult.xml'
$DLL_PATH = "tests.dll"
$xmlsettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$xmlsettings.Indent = $true
$xmlsettings.IndentChars = "`t"
$XmlWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create("$logdir\TestResult.xml", $xmlsettings)
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('assemblies')
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()

$xmlOld = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $XML_Path);
$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content "$logdir\TestResult.xml");

$siteCollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("assembly")
$xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//assemblies").AppendChild($siteCollectionNode)
$siteCollectionNode.SetAttribute("name", $DLL_PATH)
$siteCollectionNode.SetAttribute("total", $xmlOld.TestRun.ResultSummary.Counters.total)
$siteCollectionNode.SetAttribute("passed", $xmlOld.TestRun.ResultSummary.Counters.passed)
$siteCollectionNode.SetAttribute("failed", $xmlOld.TestRun.ResultSummary.Counters.failed)
$xmlDoc.Save($XML_NEW_PATH)

$siteCollectionNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("errors"));
$xmlDoc.Save($XML_NEW_PATH)

$subSitesNode = $siteCollectionNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("collection"))
$subSitesNode.SetAttribute("Name", "UAT Smoke Tests")
$subSitesNode.SetAttribute("total", $xmlOld.TestRun.ResultSummary.Counters.total)
$subSitesNode.SetAttribute("passed", $xmlOld.TestRun.ResultSummary.Counters.passed)
$subSitesNode.SetAttribute("failed", $xmlOld.TestRun.ResultSummary.Counters.failed)
$xmlDoc.Save($XML_NEW_PATH)

$TestResultNodes = $xmlOld.TestRun.Results.UnitTestResult 
 $TestResultNodes | ForEach-Object {
    $subSiteNameNode =  $subSitesNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("test"));
    $subSiteNameNode.SetAttribute("method",$xmlOld.TestRun.Results.UnitTestResult.testName)
    $subSiteNameNode.SetAttribute("result", $xmlOld.TestRun.Results.UnitTestResult.outcome)

    $subSiteNameNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("output"))
    $xmlDoc.Save($XML_NEW_PATH)

    $ListsElement =  $subSiteNameNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("traits"));
    $ListElement = $ListsElement.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("trait"));
    $ListElement.SetAttribute("name", "Category")
    $ListElement.SetAttribute("value", $xmlOld.TestRun.Results.UnitTestResult.testName)
    $xmlDoc.Save($XML_NEW_PATH)
}
return $XML_NEW_PATH
```

}

Works almost fine, it just puts all the testname and output values in each name and value attribute, like this:

```
<collection Name="UAT Smoke Tests" total="12" passed="0" failed="12">
  <test method="Should_Search_LeaseByBookingStatusCommenced_Successfully Should_Search_LegalEntity_Successfully Should_Search_SequesnceNumberLease_Successfully Should_Search_PayableInvoice_Successfully Should_Search_CustomerByStatus_Successfully Should_Search_LeaseByBookingStatusPending_Successfully Should_Search_VendorByName_Successfully Should_Search_CustomerByNumber_Successfully Should_Search_VendorByNumber_Successfully Should_Search_CustomerByName_Successfully Should_Search_InvoiceNumber_Successfully Should_Search_CustomerByAlias_Successfully" result="Failed Failed Failed Failed Failed Failed Failed Failed Failed Failed Failed Failed">
    <output />
    <traits>
      <trait name="Category" value="Should_Search_LeaseByBookingStatusCommenced_Successfully Should_Search_LegalEntity_Successfully Should_Search_SequesnceNumberLease_Successfully Should_Search_PayableInvoice_Successfully Should_Search_CustomerByStatus_Successfully Should_Search_LeaseByBookingStatusPending_Successfully Should_Search_VendorByName_Successfully Should_Search_CustomerByNumber_Successfully Should_Search_VendorByNumber_Successfully Should_Search_CustomerByName_Successfully Should_Search_InvoiceNumber_Successfully Should_Search_CustomerByAlias_Successfully" />
    </traits>
  </test>
</collection>
```

How do I get the first set of values in the first test tag method and value attribute(and ofcourse, for the trait tag Category attribute), second set in the second tags and so on?

I researched this online but couldn't find anything similar to this case, would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, leaving here the solution for those in the same situation.
I used arrays to keep each attribute value and switched for ForEach-Object to a simple for loop. See bellow just that part of the code:

```
  For ($i = 1; $i -lt $xmlOld.TestRun.ResultSummary.Counters.total; $i++ ) 
    {
        $testName = $xmlOld.TestRun.Results.UnitTestResult.testName
        $testOutcome = $xmlOld.TestRun.Results.UnitTestResult.outcome
        $testOutput = $xmlOld.TestRun.Results.UnitTestResult.Output.StdOut
        $arrayTestNames = @{}
        $arrayOutcomes = @{}
        $arrayOutput = @{}
        foreach ($item in $testName) {
            $hostname = $item.Node.InnerText.Trim()
            $services = @($item.Node.ParentNode.Service)
            foreach ($service in $services)
            {
            $arrayTestNames["$hostname"] += @($service.Trim())}
            }
            $arrayTestNames

        foreach ($result in $testOutcome) {
            $hostname = $result.Node.InnerText.Trim()
            $services = @($result.Node.ParentNode.Service)
            foreach ($service in $services)
            {
            $arrayOutcomes["$hostname"] += @($service.Trim())}
            }
            $arrayOutcomes
        foreach ($output in $testName) {
            $hostname = $output.Node.InnerText.Trim()
            $services = @($output.Node.ParentNode.Service)
            foreach ($service in $services)
            {
            $arrayOutput["$hostname"] += @($service.Trim())}
            }
            $arrayOutput

    $subSiteNameNode =  $subSitesNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("test"));
    $subSiteNameNode.SetAttribute("method", $testName[$i])
    $subSiteNameNode.SetAttribute("result", $testOutcome[$i])
    
    $outputNode = $subSiteNameNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("output"))
    $outputNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateTextNode($testOutput[$i])); 

    $xmlDoc.Save($XML_NEW_PATH)

    $ListsElement =  $subSiteNameNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("traits"));
    $ListElement = $ListsElement.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("trait"));
    $ListElement.SetAttribute("name", "Category")
    $ListElement.SetAttribute("value", $testName[$i])
    $xmlDoc.Save($XML_NEW_PATH)
    }
```

## }

```
return $XML_NEW_PATH
```